# backuupc connection refused after upgrade

Tags: update, backuppc

I conducted an upgrade to Debian Buster and lifted the backuppc version as well. Now I get an error when logging in to the website

```
This CGI script (/backuppc/index.cgi) is unable to connect to the BackupPC server on backuppc port -1.
The error was: unix connect: Connection refused.
Perhaps the BackupPC server is not running or there is a configuration error. Please report this to your Sys Admin.
```

`Systemctl` shows backuppc as `active (exited)`.

Answer (score 0):

Backuppc cannot connect to the unix socket. Create the neccessary folder and restart the service.

```
# mkdir /var/run/backuppc
# chown backuppc:backuppc /var/run/backuppc
# systemctl restart backuppc
```